# Howto read sets in Redis?

Tags: redis, node-redis

I have a simple `redis set` with over 1 millons notes. I add dat using `sadd`

How can I read this set by partition?

I mean read first 100 000 keys and after 200 000?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by "by partition", but if you want to read it in chunks, `SSCAN` is your friend.

```
SSCAN key cursor [MATCH pattern] [COUNT count]
```

You start with a value of 0 in the cursor, and you get the next cursor id and `COUNT` elements each time. When there is nothing more to read you get a cursor of 0.

For example:

```
# let's add 14 elements to a set
127.0.0.1:6379> SADD myset e1 e2 e3 e4 e5 e6 e7 e8 e9 e10 e11 e12 e13 e14
(integer) 14

# now let's scan it from the "beginning" (notice that it's not ordered)
127.0.0.1:6379> SSCAN myset 0 COUNT 10
1) "3"
2)  1) "e8"
    2) "e10"
    3) "e2"
    4) "e11"
    5) "e7"
    6) "e3"
    7) "e14"
    8) "e4"
    9) "e6"
   10) "e9"

# we got a cursor id of 3, let's give that to the next iteration!
127.0.0.1:6379> SSCAN myset 3 COUNT 10
1) "0"
2) 1) "e13"
   2) "e12"
   3) "e5"
   4) "e1"

# now we got a cursor id of 0, meaning we're done
```

Comment: I have function in Python, that accepts parameters: self, name,cursor, match, count. And I have set is `apps`. How should I write parameters?

Comment: Is it right? `items = r.sscan("apps", 400000, None, 700000)`?